# In magento 1.9 New Order email not receive

Tags: magento-1.9

In magento, new order email is not working. I have set up "store email addresses" also, not working.

Comment: more information than "is not working" would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Check if your **CRON** is running or not. Default Magento adds order emails to queue & then sends it via scheduled CRON.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :-

a- You've to set CRON, by default Magento sent the email by CRON.

b- Or if you don't want set CRON, then simply open `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php`

& replace

```
$mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send(); 

with

$mailer-> send();
```